# python - Split an image based on white space

Tags: python, image, opencv, split

I am trying to split [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T18Ux.png) into equal sections where the "white space" in between the rows of bubbles is, and then take all of those sub images and line them up in one long image, so that the questions are vertically ordered. How can I use python to split the image this way? I am doing this to use OpenCV to grade the bubble sheet. Please keep in mind that I am new to python(but not coding), so it would be good if you could explain what each block of code is intended to do.

Comment: have you tried contours?

Comment: yes, I am trying to split it and reorganize it into 1 row because I don't know a way to sort the contours in any other way.

Comment: https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/tutorial_segmentation.html . Just look at the technique. I 'm not suggesting you any library. Your problem is close enough.

Comment: opencv too has the similar tools.

Comment: I thought you needed the bubbles.

Comment: Another way is to draw 4 black lines via ms paint. Then one of the easier techniques can be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Color threshold on the border color as a mask
- Use the mask to make the border white
- Dilate the mask a little to include the black border lines also
- Convert that result to grayscale
- Otsu Threshold
- Apply morphology open to connect the text into column-like regions and invert
- Get the external contours and their bounding boxes in a list
- Compute the maximum width from all the boxes
- Loop over each box, crop with padding and stack with the previous box
- Save results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read input image
img = cv2.imread('abcd_test.png')

# define border color
lower = (0, 80, 110)
upper = (0, 120, 150)

# threshold on border color
mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)

# dilate threshold
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (15, 15))
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel)

# recolor border to white
img[mask==255] = (255,255,255)

# convert img to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# otsu threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU )[1] 

# apply morphology open
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (17,17))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
morph = 255 - morph

# find contours and bounding boxes
bboxes = []
bboxes_img = img.copy()
contours = cv2.findContours(morph, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
for cntr in contours:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cntr)
    cv2.rectangle(bboxes_img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 255), 1)
    bboxes.append((x,y,w,h))

# get largest width of bboxes
maxwidth = max(bboxes)[2]

# sort bboxes on x coordinate
def takeFirst(elem):
    return elem[0]

bboxes.sort(key=takeFirst)

# stack cropped boxes with 10 pixels padding all around
result = np.full((1,maxwidth+20,3), (255,255,255), dtype=np.uint8)
for bbox in bboxes:
    (x,y,w,h) = bbox
    crop = img[y-10:y+h+10, x-10:x+maxwidth+10]
    result = np.vstack((result, crop))

# save result
cv2.imwrite("abcd_test_mask.jpg", mask)
cv2.imwrite("abcd_test_white_border.jpg", img)
cv2.imwrite("abcd_test_thresh.jpg", thresh)
cv2.imwrite("abcd_test_morph.jpg", morph)
cv2.imwrite("abcd_test_bboxes.jpg", bboxes_img)
cv2.imwrite("abcd_test_column_stack.png", result)

# show images
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
cv2.imshow("img", img)
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("morph", morph)
cv2.imshow("bboxes_img", bboxes_img)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Border mask image:

[image]

Image with border changed to white:

[image]

Threshold and morphology image:

[image]

Bounding Boxes image:

[image]

Cropped and stacked columns image:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to sort the contours so that the problems are numbered in the correct way?

Comment: Sort on the x coordinate of the boxes. See my modified answer above.